# Copy parent's class to it's parent's parent's class if checkbox is checked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox, parent

**Examples**

Before:

```
<ul>    
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1"></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2 current-cat">   
        <input type="checkbox" id="2"></li>       <-checked
</ul>
```

I'd like to have "cat-item-#number#" in it's parent's class when it's also "current-cat" or when it's checkbox's state is checked. (checkbox can start checked by default)

After Jquery:

```
<ul class="cat-item-2"> 
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1"></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2 current-cat">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2"></li>       <-checked
</ul>
```

After checking the first checkbox:

```
<ul class="cat-item-1 cat-item-2">  
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1"></li>       <-checked
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2 current-cat">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2"></li>       <-checked
</ul>
```

Then after unchecking the second checkbox:

```
<ul class="cat-item-1"> 
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1"></li>       <-checked
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2 current-cat">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do it? I don't care if the first "cat-item" from class get's copied too.

I don't know jquery, but I'd like to do something like this:

Initialize:

```
$if(":checkbox") is checked -> $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass((this.parent().class());
```

Onclick:

```
$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
if(":checkbox") is checked -> $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass((this.parent().class());
if ((":checkbox") is unchecked) -> remove it's class from paren.parent's class});
```

Comment: post your jquery code in the question

Comment: added some code but i don't know jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$(".cat-item [type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $(".current-cat").removeClass("current-cat");

    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cat-item-" + $(this).attr("id"));
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cat-item-" + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The code below will run on page load and will take care of adding the classes of the already checked checkboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cat-item [type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked"))
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cat-item-" + $(this).attr("id"));
        else
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cat-item-" + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Here is a working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfKamran/sdh53thk/1/)

Comment: Thank you! How can I add this to pageload too? not just for change function but before? 
if ($(this).prop("checked"))
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cat-item-" + $(this).attr("id"));

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chkbox1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cat-item-1");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cat-item-1");
        }
    });
    $("#chkbox2").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cat-item-2");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cat-item-2");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

But cat-item-# can be anything, cat-item-3 ... to ... cat-item-250
How can I edit that part to include parent's class?

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

This works for the pattern `cat-item-#number#` (even if there are more than one such patterns and also independent of `id`)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(){

    $parent = $(this).parent();
    var cls = $parent.attr('class').match(/[\w-]*cat-item-[\w-]*/g);
        cls = cls.join(' ');

       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           $parent.parent().addClass(cls);
       }
        else{
            $parent.parent().removeClass(cls);
        }
    });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g6mw0zn/4/)